# html5 dropdown menu not loading correctly over hover

Tags: css, html

I am a beginner in programming.Now i am assigned with the task of making a site with html5 and css.The issue what i am facing is

I have a horizontal menu bar with vertical sub menu will come on hover.

**3 main tabs home ,health,safety**

under that i have sub menus

when i am clicking **all main menus  are working fine**.

But when clicking home -health-health sub menu(it works fine) -safety sub menu(it wont work fine)

this is error i am getting when i click fire hazards directly after health.
No webpage was found for the web address:
 http://file:///C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/a/health/safety/fire_hazards.html

**the web address shown above is incorrect.
i have kept fire hazards in safety-firehazards folder
and not in health -safety-firehazards folder**

why is the path is showing wrong

```
 <div id="menu"> <!--starts of menu-->
  <ul >
   <li><a href="index1.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="health.html">Health</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="health/personal_hygiene.html">Personal Hygiene</a>`enter   </li>
     <li><a href="health/food_hygiene.html">Food Hygeiene</a></li>

    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="safety/fire_hazards.html">Fire Hazards</a></li>
     <li><a href="safety/cooking_gas.html">Cooking Gas</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div><!--end of menu-->
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
 }
 #menu ul li a:hover{
    color:#c1d82f;
}
#menu ul .current {
    color: #b13932;
}
#menu li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 4px 0px;
}
#menu  li {
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   list-style-type:none;
}
#menu  li a {
    display: block;
    padding:10px 45px;
}
#menu ul :after{
    content:".";
    height:0px;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#menu ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
#menu ul ul li {
    width:100%;
}
#menu ul ul li a{
    border-right:none;
    padding:5px 5px;

}

 /* end of menu */

}
```

Comment: please provide the correct link and make your question clear

Comment: @Amit Singh: http://jsfiddle.net/nbqj8r3t/

Comment: The error is causing due to the `path` you have provided in the `a` tag

Comment: You have to again provide `path` to that page from where you want to go to another page

Comment: @Amitsingh:thanks for your suggestion.Could you please mention how to give it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code also:

```css
#menu {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 background:#ccc;
}
nav {
 position:relative;
}
nav ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
nav ul li {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
}
nav ul li a {
 font:bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 color:#333;
 padding:7px 10px;
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
}
nav ul li:hover > a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#005ba0;
}
nav ul li a.current {
 background:#005ba0;
 color:#fff;
}
nav ul ul {
 min-width:200px;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 z-index:666;
 background:#eee;
 display:none;
}
nav li:hover > ul {
 display:block;
}
nav ul ul ul {
 left:100%;
 top:0;
}
nav ul ul li {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
}
nav ul ul a {
 padding:7px 10px;
 display:block;
 color:#777;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
 text-align:left;
}
nav ul ul a:hover {
 background:#ddd;
}
nav ul ul a.current {
 background:#dddd;
 color:#005ba0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index1.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="health.html">Health</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="health/personal_hygiene.html">Personal Hygiene`enter</a></li>
     <li><a href="health/food_hygiene.html">Food Hygeiene</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="safety/fire_hazards.html">Fire Hazards</a></li>
     <li><a href="safety/cooking_gas.html">Cooking Gas</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: om_: thanks ton for your inputs.its working fine now

Comment: i trouble i am facing now is i kept <nav>on all my parent html and child html files but then again i am getting the same issue.    No webpage was found for the web address: file:///C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/drop_down/health/safety/electrical_safety.html. why is it reading the wrong folder structure.my electrical_safety is just inside safety file and not environment-safety-electrical_safety.html

Comment: can you provide online link of your code or a screenshot of your folder structure

Comment: :it was relative path issue...now its working fine